# Racket as scripting language in a game engine

Tags: c++, dll, scheme, racket, game-engine

I would like to add scripting capabilities to my C++ game engine.

I have `Engine.exe`, `Physics.dll`, `Audio.dll` and I'm adding `Scripting.dll` which is a high-level Racket wrapper.

`Engine.exe` loads `Physics.dll` and sets up physics world, loads `Audio.dll` and sets up audio world. It is supposed to load `Scripting.dll`, to set up bindings to `Physics.dll`, `Audio.dll` and to load game scripts.

AFAIK there are two possible ways to embed Racket into a C++ program:

- [As Extension](http://docs.racket-lang.org/inside/Writing_Racket_Extensions.html)
- [As Foreign Interface](http://docs.racket-lang.org/foreign/index.html)

Using [*Foreign Interface*](http://docs.racket-lang.org/foreign/index.html) seems bizarre due to necessity to load `Physics.dll`, `Audio.dll` two times: first from `Engine.exe` and then from the game script.

Writing [*Extensions*](http://docs.racket-lang.org/inside/Writing_Racket_Extensions.html) looks more appealing, because it allows doing script bindings on C++ side. On the other hand you have to build your extension with `raco ctool`, link it with `mzdyn` object file — which looks awkward as well: why not make `mzdyn` a static library?

I would like to implement a single method, e.g. `setupScriptBindings()`, both in `Physics.dll` and in `Audio.dll`, and to call it from `Engine.exe` at the startup.

Is there a straightforward way to do it?

Comment: Hm, maybe [this](http://docs.racket-lang.org/inside/embedding.html) description helps.

Comment: Hm ... the links you provide talk about embedding C/other code **into** a Racket program. From you description, I think you want it the other way around, e.g. embedding Racket into your C++ application: http://docs.racket-lang.org/inside/embedding.html
Though the easiest and probably cleanest solution would be to define some sort of protocol for controlling your game entities, and then start racket as a new process, communicating using sockets or some other IPC mechanism.

Comment: Offtopic: Racket has been successfully used in video game production by Naughty Dog. See [«Racket on the Playstation 3»](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oSmqbnhHp1c) and [«State-Based Scripting in Uncharted 2: Among Thieves»](http://www.gameenginebook.com/resources/gdc09-statescripting-uncharted2.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

Having used both the extension and FFI methods of connecting Racket to C code, I have to say the FFI approach is *much* nicer. The bindings in Racket to the C functions are well specified and robust and dealing with C types in Racket is very nice. The only drawback to using the FFI approach is that, AFAIK, your Racket program must be the driver application.

With the embedding approach your C/C++ executable is the driver, but declaring the interface with the Racket code is much more manual and error prone. Not to mention that you have to either figure out raco ctool and replicate it or have racket's build system take over yours. For our purposes we wound up extracting the Racket sources and building it ourselves. I don't really recommend that approach.

Ultimately for my purposes having my application be a Racket application with a foreign .DLL/.so file that it loaded for C functions worked best, but it sounds like you may be stuck with the embedding approach.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I need an embedded solution. Though you say it might be tough, building Racket from source seems more appealing to me. If you could provide an example of «native» ↔ «script» binding from your embedding-based approach, it would be very helpful. What form of script execution did you choose: plain text, [bytecode](http://docs.racket-lang.org/raco/make.html) or [standalone executable](http://docs.racket-lang.org/raco/exe.html)?

Comment: We would use plain text or bytecode. Bytecode is noticeably faster, but you have to take care that it is updated or that Racket compiles it when necessary.

Comment: And our native <-> script binding looked just like the example in the docs... nothing special.